# Visual Studio C Syntax Coloring issue

Tags: c, visual-studio, syntax

I used to work with Eclipse for my **C** firmware for a STM32-based board, and now I'm switching to Visual Studio 2017 + VisualGDB.

The project is working, but there's something strange for the syntax highlighting and coloring.

Pictures to understand better:

**Highlighting totally lost [I placed the cursor in the variable "timer"]**

[image]

**Syntax Coloring when the file is saved [No colors]**

[image]

**Syntax Coloring when editing the file [OK!]**

[image]

*If I edit the file and press Ctrl+S, the Colors go away!*

I already reset the editor colors to default in Options, repaired the VS installation and rebooted PC, etc.

In other C++ and C# projects, everything is fine.

Comment: Probably unrelated... But add some spaces to your code.

Comment: Added but still the same  :/

Comment: Use Help => Send Feedback => Report a Problem.  Looks like a bug, probably related to some project/plug-in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, setting **Options > VisualGDB > General > Enable Clang Intellisense by Default** to **False** solved it.

Until now didn't see what I've lost by disabling it, but at least the colors and the selections are back to normal!

Thanks for the help!